Symmetry Arguments in Radiation Corrections: Gauge vs Custodial and Accidental Symmetries
I'm confused about the symmetry arguments in the radiation correction.
For photon mass, gauge symmetry protects it's mass term. I understand this as a consequence of Ward's identity.
$$\langle\partial^\mu J_\mu\mathcal O… \rangle$$
But for the case of electron mass and the LFV, I am confused,

it is commonly said that electron mass is protected by custodial chiral symmetry, but Ward's identity is the result of gauge symmetry. Do people usually consider Ward's identity-like thing in this case?

The Standard Model has U(1) symmetry on lepton flavour, but this symmetry is accidental. Is accidental symmetry can be custodial (does it forbid some terms)? If not, what breaks the same arguments that are used in gauge and chiral symmetry?



Can you clarify what you mean by "The Standard Model has U(1) symmetry on lepton flavour"? The weak interactions violate flavor conservation. There is a conservation law for lepton number, is that what you mean?

Also there are Ward identities for global symmetries as well as gauge symmetries: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward%E2%80%93Takahashi_identity
